# Celery task: is there any function to call initialize task in the base class

Tags: python, celery

I made BaseTask which is base class of Celery tasks what I implement.
I wanna have init function which can be called at the task start.
Is there any function like `on_start`?
Thanks in advance.

```
class BaseTask(celery.Task):
    def on_failure(self, exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo):
        # Some logics
        super().on_failure(exc, task_id, args, kwargs, einfo)

    def on_success(self, retval, task_id, args, kwargs):
        # Some logics
        super().on_success(retval, task_id, args, kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

No worries, I found the solution by upgrading celery to the latest version 5.2.7 which supports `before_start` handler and here is origin Celery support team's discussion
Issue: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4110
MR: https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/6923
Thanks Celery support team.